# I am getting "The LINQ expression could not be translated" exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When I want to use `Any()` expression in the `Where()` filtering that I send to the database, I get the following exception.

**Exception :**

> The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

If I filter with `Where()` after getting all the records from the database it works correctly. But I want to get filtered data from database.

**My codes that I got the exception are as follows.**

```
var firstList = await _firstRepository
                     .FilterByAsync(x => x.IsActive);

var secondList = await _secondRepository
                       .FilterByAsync(x => !firstList
                                           .Any(y =>
                                                y.CategoryId == x.CategoryId &&
                                                y.Type == x.Type)
                                      );
```

**Note : There are 2 different repositories as the queries have to go to 2 different tables.**

**Also, I have a filter method inside my generic repository.**

```
public async Task<List<TEntity>> FilterByAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return await _entities.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
}
```

I hope I have expressed my problem well.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Use `Contains` instead of `Any`

Comment: I can't check if there is a secondEntity in the firstEntity list with Contains().

Comment: Chain AsEnumerable() before the call to filterAsync, if you don’t mind it being evaluated client side. Else you need to use contain, firstordefault or .count

Comment: There is no out of the box support for this in EF (only for single property using `Contains` - `var idList = new List<int>...; ...Where(e => idList.Contains(e.Id)))`. For multiple properties you need either use `Union` in cycle, or build predicate `Expression` manually or via 3rd party library.